# hide last 3 input type text via css from multiple input

Tags: css, html

If i have a multiple input type text and i wants to show only 3 top .
I used this html and css. but hide fail.

http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/qecCC/

**HTML**

```
<div id="urlLinksInput"> 
    <p> 
        <input id="inputurl0" name="inputurl[]" type="text" class="txtinput"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="inputurl1" name="inputurl[]" type="text" class="txtinput"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="inputurl2" name="inputurl[]" type="text" class="txtinput"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="inputurl3" name="inputurl[]" type="text" class="txtinput"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="inputurl4" name="inputurl[]" type="text" class="txtinput"> 
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #urlLinksInput p input:nth-child(n+3) { display: none; }
```

Comment: why don't you add a specific class for the input that you want to hide? just add class like hidden and add this style in your css, .hidden{display:none;}, it will be easy for you later if you want to show it up, just use jquery find this class.

Comment: your suggestion is good. but i need to hide this in responsive.. only hide for 320*480.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#urlLinksInput p:nth-child(n+3) input { 
   display: none; /* ^----this must be here,as <p> has only ONE child,
                                            and that is <input>*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qecCC/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML5 `hidden` attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-hidden):

```
<input type="text" hidden>
```

...with this fallback CSS for non-supporting browsers:

```
[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qecCC/2/)

### Edit

Even better use [`input[type=hidden]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html). It works just like a text input, and you can interact with it via JavaScript, yet it's hidden:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Comment: Sorry but i accepted ans already..
But gave you up vote for this.